# Edit and Update method is working.But,how to retrieve the values from database while editing the existing values

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-mysql

I'm Creating Small Size of Web Interface.I created the edit button in Web Interface.But ,it's not working.It Creating as a new Entry in Database.Can anyone help me.One more thing is How to retrieve the values from database while editing existing values.Thanks for advanced.

Here is The Python Code:

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
   type=StringField('type')

@app.route('/newuser', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def add_user():

     form = UserForm()
     if form.validate_on_submit():
         user_details = {
        'type': form.type.data

    }
    sqlsession.add(user_details)
    return redirect(url_for('vehicle_type'))
return render_template('vehicletype.html', form=form)

@app.route('/control/edit/<int:id>',methods=['POST','GET'])
def edit(id):
    qry=sqlsession.query(Vehicletype).filter(Vehicletype.id==id).first()
    form = UserForm(request.form, object=qry)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    form.populate_obj(qry)
    sqlsession.update(qry)
    sqlsession.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('vehicle_type'))
return render_template('vehicletype.html', form=form)
```

Here is the Templates of the vehicletype.html Code:

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block head %}
  {{super()}}
  {% endblock %}

  {% block navbar %}
  {{super()}}
  {% endblock %}


 {% block content %}

  <div class="row">
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">
        <em class="fa fa-home"></em>
    </a></li>
    <li class="active">Vehicletype > Create Vehicletype</li>
</ol>
</div><!--/.row-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<form role="form" action="/post/vehicletype" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
    <label>VehicleType: </label>
    <input name="type" class="form-control" placeholder="enter vehicletype">
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit   ">
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the vehicletypedetails.html code:

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block head %}
  {{super()}}
  {% endblock %}


  {% block navbar %}
  {{super()}}
  {% endblock %}


  {% block content %}

  <div class="row">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">
        <em class="fa fa-home"></em>
    </a></li>
    <li class="active">Vehicletype>View</li>
</ol>
</div><!--/.row-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">

<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        Id
    </th>
    <th>
       VehicleType
    </th>

    <th>
        Dateofsub
    </th>

    <!--<th>
        Control
    </th>-->
    <th>
        Delete
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
{% for values in vehicletype   %}
<tr>
    <th>{{values.id}}</th>
    <td>{{values.type}}</td>
    <td>{{values.dateofsub}}</td>
    <!--<td><a href="/Control/resetuserpass/{{values.id}}" class="btn btn-info">Reset Password</a></td>-->
    <td><a href=" /vehicletype/deleteuser/{{values.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
    <td><a href=" /control/edit/{{values.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">edit</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<a href = "/page/vehicletype"> <em class="fa fa-xl fa-plus-circle color-blue" ></em> </a>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have been trying to solve this issue for 6 days .But I Could not find any solution. Please  could you help me anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to edit an existing entry has a route of `/control/edit/<int:id>`, but your form you're using to submit the user-changes is pointing at a different route located at `/post/vehicletype`.

You'll need to change your return from:

```
 return render_template('vehicletype.html', form=form)
```

to:

```
 return render_template('vehicletype.html', form=form, car_id=id)
```

And then change your html code from:

```
<form role="form" action="/post/vehicletype" method="post">
```

to:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ url_for('edit', id=car_id) }}" method="post">
```

With that in place, your form code will be getting submitted to the correct route for processing.

Comment: This Is working.but,how to retrieve the values from database while editing the existing.